# MMS messages text disappears

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, mms, troubleshooting

When I receive an MMS message (Android 4.1.2), I can see by the momentary preview that there is text to the message, but when I open it, I cannot find the text, only the image.  Anybody have the solution?  Thanks.

Comment: What phone do you have? Different manufacturers use different SMS/MMS apps.

Comment: Sorry about the omission:  Samsung Galaxy S2.  Thanks.